# Regex not stripping periods

Tags: php, regex

Why is my regex not stripping out the periods? The end result should output only alpha and numeric characters, plus '-'s, but I keep getting periods in the output. I've tried trim($string, '.') but didn't work. Help Please!

Update! I've updated the code with the correct solution. Thanks!

```
<?php
protected $trimCharacters = "/[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]/";
protected $validWords = "/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+/";

private function cleanUpNoise($inputText){

  $this->inputText = preg_replace($this->trimCharacters, '', $this->inputText);
  $this->inputText = strtolower($this->inputText);
  $this->inputText = preg_match_all($this->validWords, $this->inputText, $matches);

  return $matches;
}
?>
```

Comment: would removing all non alphanumeric or - chars implict the removing of a whitespace char, a colon and a +? So removing everything matching your `$splitPattern` woud be sense less beacause your next step, your `$trimCharacters` implicts the `$splitPattern`?

Comment: What does implicts mean?

Comment: You're right, but even with removing $splitPattern, my regex is still letting ." through. If I test it at regexpal.com, it says it should work.

Comment: Sorry my english went wrong. Must be 'implicate'. Implicit means that it is includet. So `/[\s,\+]+/` removes these sorts of characters... And `/[^\w-]/g` removes all characters that are non alphanumeric or '-'... So all characters wich have been removed by `[\s,\+]+` would also been removed by `/[^\w-]/g`. I think it gets clear if you change the order of them... If you first run `/[^\w-]/g` on your string there wont be neither any whitspace nor colon nor plussign in the string anymore, so why running `[\s,\+]+` on the string? there is nothing it can do anymore, bacause [^\w-] implicates it.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex only fetches the first time you pattern matches... try setting the global flag in you pattern like

`"/[\\s,\\+]+/g"`

Something like

```
'/[\s,\+]+/g'
'/[^\w-]/g'
```

would be your expressions, you are looking for... be aware: you have to escape your backslashes... if not php will try to interpret `\s` `\+` `\w`...

use it like

```
protected $splitPattern = '/[\\s,\\+]+/g';
protected $trimCharacters = '/[^\\w-]/g';
```

Edit:

Ohh... cant you simplify it to:

```
$this->inputText = preg_replace($this->splitPattern, '', $this->inputText);
$this->inputText = preg_replace($this->trimCharacters, '', $this->inputText);
```

Comment: Is that global modifier recognized in php like that?

Comment: Ohhh sorry, you can leave out the g-flag of course, since:

"Limit:
    The maximum possible replacements for each pattern in each subject string. Defaults to -1 (no limit)."